# How to change the vertical line gap of Label?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

How can the vertical line gap of Label be changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you are asking about changing the space between lines when a spark Label is showing multiple lines of text.  To do that, you set the lineHeight style to a percent value:

ActionScript:

```
myLabel.setStyle("lineHeight", "140%");
```

MXML:

```
<s:Label lineHeight="140%"/>
```

According to the documentation the default value is 120%.  Hope that helps.